# Does $O(1/n)$ imply $o(1)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Assume that $u_n$ is a real sequence such that $u_n = O(1/n)$ as $n$ tends to infinity. It means that there exists a positive $M$ and integer $n_0$ such that $
\left|\frac{u_n}{n^{-1}}\right| \leq M  \text { for all } n \geq n_0.$

So, $\left|u_n \cdot n \right| \leq M  \text { for all } n \geq n_0.$

However, $n$ can become very large and therefore in order to stay bounded $u_n$ should get closer and closer to $0$.

Therefore, $u_n$ is $o(1)$?

Comment: $u_n=\mathcal{O}(1/n)\implies \exists M>0 \,\, \lvert u_n \rvert \leqslant M/n \,\, \forall n \implies \lvert u_n \rvert \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ since $M/n \to 0$.

Comment: @eryna You're right: specifically, $\lvert u_n\rvert\le\varepsilon$ for all $n\ge \max\{n_0,M/\varepsilon\}$.

Comment: More generally, if $f\in o(g)$ then $O(f)\subseteq o(g)$.